# how to start an application required file in relative path

Tags: pywinauto

I am using `pywinauto` to start a `exe`. This `exe` requires a file `reqFile.txt`, and the `exe` read this file by `open("./reqFile.txt")`. Since the `reqFile.txt` and `exe` are in the same file, `open("./reqFile.txt")` works.

But, if `pywinauto` to start this exe, the `pywinauto` code and `exe` is not located at the same folder. For example, the `pywinauto` code is located at `D://`, but `exe` is located at `C://App`. When `pywinauto.application.Application().start('C://App//xxx.exe')`, it would report that `no such file "reqFile.txt"`, because `reqFile.txt` is located at `C://App` rather than `D://`.

How can I fix this problem? Any suggestion is appreciated~~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.chdir` to change the working directory of the python app to the location of `reqFile.txt` so the new process will also use this as a working directory.